# Maths, esp. Godel, and poetry

Tags: formal-languages, incompleteness, turing-machines, meta-math

At the risk of being an interloper:
I'm a poet with a bit of mathematical training.   Right now I've got a grant from the Arts Council of Northern Ireland to write a collection (loosely) based on the life and ideas of Kurt Gödel.  Check these out:

http://vimeo.com/86988003
http://www.artscouncil-ni.org/news/arts-council-announces-aces-recipients-2014

I'm looking for mathematicians I can strike up an email correspondence with to try to see what parallels we can find between maths and poetry.  For example, how closely does the idea of completeness in a formal system correspond to the idea of metaphor in a poem?  I'm keen to learn from mathematicians and to see how their ideas might feed into the poetic work.

Get back to me if you're interested via mattkirkham2004@yahoo.co.uk, or feel free to pass this on to others if you think they may be.

Regards,

Matt

Comment: You might be interested in the area of algorithmic poetry. There is some interesting material out there as well about formal languages and poetry. I came across this one in talking with my brother a while back- http://www.ijiet.org/papers/99-T038.pdf. It deals with using Context-Free Grammars to analyze a type of poem. Good luck!

Comment: Relatedly, David Foster Wallace wrote a short story dedicated to Godel, called Here and There, about a poet who wishes to write about technology: http://books.google.com/books?id=cn_rcmInIS8C&pg=PA149#v=onepage